# Cancel query execution in pyscopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-db-api

How would one go about cancelling execution of a query statement using pyscopg2 (the python Postgres driver)?

As an example, let's say I have the following code:

```
import psycopg2
cnx_string = "something_appropriate"

conn = psycopg2.connect(cnx_string)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("long_running_query")
```

Then I want to cancel the execution of that long running query from another thread - what method would I have to call on the connection/cursor objects to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cancel a query by calling the [`pg_cancel_backend(pid)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) PostgreSQL function in a separate connection.

You can know the PID of the backend to cancel from the [`connection.get_backend_pid()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.get_backend_pid) method of psycopg2 (available from version 2.0.8).

Comment: Note that the user sending `pg_cancel_backend(pid)` must be a superuser.

Answer (score 2):

The connection object has a cancel member. Using this and threading you could use

```
sqltimeout = threading.Timer(sql_timeout_seconds, conn.cancel)
sqltimeout.start()
```

When the timer expires, the cancel is sent to the connection and an exception will be raised by the server. 
Don't forget to cancel the timer when the query normally finishes....

```
sqltimeout.cancel()
```